# powershell to compare 2 csv files and where a duplicate fields the rest of the row is updated

Tags: powershell, csv

This is difficult to explain, but I will try my best.

I have 2 CSV files called file1.csv and file2.csv...

What I would like is for `file1.csv` to try and match entries in its first column to entries in the first column of the `file2.csv`.  If a match exists then I want the row from File1.csv to overwrite that particular row in `file2.csv`.  I don't mind if it outputs to another file.  Please help :)

File1:

```
uniqueID, first, surname, address
1, Joe, Bloggs, 32 Cheddar Rd 
2, Bill, Gates, 21 SOmewhere Road
3, Tim, Burton, 24 This Lane
```

File2:

```
uniqueID, first, surname, address
1, Joe, Bloggs, 34 BLAH BLAH
2, Bill, Gates, 43 BLAH BLAH
3, Tim, Burton, 65 BLAH BLAH
4, Kai, Peters, 42 BLAH BLAH
5, Gay, Thomas, 65 BLAH BLAH
```

Output:

```
uniqueID, first, surname, address
1, Joe, Bloggs, 32 Cheddar Rd 
2, Bill, Gates, 21 SOmewhere Road
3, Tim, Burton, 24 This Lane
4, Kai, Peters, 42 BLAH BLAH
5, Gay, Thomas, 65 BLAH BLAH
```

Thanks
Spencer

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Any particular problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should show some code of what you tried to get help, but since this is your first post I'll help you along.

```
$file1 = Import-Csv file1.txt
$file2 = Import-Csv file2.txt

$file2 | % {$Entry = $_; $file1 | ? {$_.uniqueID -eq $Entry.uniqueID} | % {$Entry.address = $_.address}}

$Results = @()

$file2  | % {$Results += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"uniqueID" = $_.uniqueID; "first" = $_.First; "surname" = $_.surname; "address" = $_.address} }

$Results | Export-Csv -Path file3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```